# Create & Retrieve Nested Records with iOS SDK

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, master-detail, create-records

How can I create and retrieve nested records with the iOS SDK? Is this even possible?

I have 2 objects with master-detail relationship and I'd like to be able to create and retrieve them in one request if possible...

Comment: With Salesforce, regardless of the SDK/API you use, you will have to make 2 requests to create 2 objects... unless both objects are of the same type.

Comment: @SebastianKessel Unless I'm reading [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_create.htm) wrong, it seems you can with the REST api. However if I am wrong, is it possible to create multiple objects with the SDK?

Comment: You seem to be reading it right. I stand corrected. The good news is, if you build the XML with a similar structure as what was described in that doc and point it to the correct URL (example: https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/composite/tree/XXX/ , where XXX is the name of the parent object) then you can get it to work.

If you need help on how to do that in iOS... I am afraid that might be a question for the xcode forum

Comment: @SebastianKessel Cool well thanks for your help anyway!